# Is it possible to disable typescript autocast when field names are the same?

Tags: typescript, casting, tsconfig

Consider the following class:

```
Class Coordinate {
    public readonly latitude: number;
    public readonly longitude: number;
    constructor(latitude: number, longitude: number) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
}
```

Now, let's say that I have another class named CoordinateDto, which is completely similar to Coordinate class for now, but represents a Dto object. Its field names are dependant to some other code that may change, but for now it has the same field names and types as Coordinate.

```
Class CoordinateDto {
    public readonly latitude: number;
    public readonly longitude: number;
    constructor(latitude: number, longitude: number) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
}
```

Typescript allows me to define a functoin like this:

```
function getCoordinate(): Coordinate {
    return new CoordinateDto(111.222, 333.444);
}
```

Is it possible to prevent typescript from accepting this? It is totally detectable at compile time, and it may cause human error (because people may use it wrong and it can lead to lots of confusion and a considerable cost for fixing later on).

I thought that maybe there is a compiler option in tsconfig that dis-allows autocasting (casting without using "any" keyword) but I couldn't find anything. Appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, it's not possible (at least as far as I know).

A class in typescript has two parts: the javascript class (the implementation) and the interface (the definition).  When you use `Coordinate` as a return type, you are telling typescript that the function must return something which fits the interface of the Coordinate class.  Since both of your classes have identical interfaces, a `CoordinateDto` does fulfill that interface and will pass the type checks.

One sort of hacky solution is to add some sort of flag property which makes the two interfaces incompatible.  `CoordinateDto` can get a property `public readonly type = 'dto';` while `Coordinate` gets `public readonly type = 'raw';`.  These are immutable string literals, so even though they are both strings they are a mismatch.  That would give you an error in your example function:

```
Type 'CoordinateDto' is not assignable to type 'Coordinate'.
  Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
    Type '"dto"' is not assignable to type '"raw"'.
```